# How proof that the set of algebraic polynomials of degree at most $k$ is not dense in $C(R^n)$

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, roots, neural-networks, dense-subspaces

I would use the function $\cos(x)$ and the property that a function of the polynomials set has at most $k$ roots and the function $\cos(x)$ can have more roots. Let me know how to proof it rigorously. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Note that the approximating polynomials need not have the same or even as many roots as the approximated function. At any rate, if you are dealing with supremum norm, any non-constant bounded function (yes, also cosine) works for this problem.